# Unable to extend layout in pug

Tags: express, pug

In my index file I extend the layout with the following markup:

```
extends layout
html
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')    
  link(rel='stylesheet',href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css')
  script(src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js')
block content
  h1= title

body

  nav
    .navbar.navbar-inverse
    .container-fluid
    .navbar-header
  a
    .navbar-brand(href='#') WebSiteName
  ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li.active
      a(href='#') Home
    li
      a(href='#') Issues
    li
      a(href='#') Page 2
    li
      a(href='#') Page 3
```

I get the following error: Only named blocks and mixins can appear at the top level of an extending template.

Googled and tried some basic fixes that didn't help

layout.pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/style.css')
  block content  
  body
   nav
    .navbar
    .container-fluid
    .navbar-header
   a
    .navbar-brand(href='#') WebSiteName
    ul.nav.navbar-nav
      li.active
        a(href='#') Home
      li
        a(href='#') Page 1
      li
        a(href='#') Page 2
      li
        a(href='#') Page 3
```

Comment: As there error message states, only named blocks and mixins can appear at the top level of an extending template. `html` and `body` are not named blocks or mixins, but they're at the top level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can share ur extend layout code? Also try giving body and it sub elements a tab.

```
extends layout


block content
    h1= title

    body
        script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')    
        link(rel='stylesheet',href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        script(src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js') 
        nav
            .navbar.navbar-inverse
            .container-fluid
            .navbar-header
        a
            .navbar-brand(href='#') WebSiteName
        ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li.active
              a(href='#') Home
            li
              a(href='#') Issues
            li
              a(href='#') Page 2
            li
              a(href='#') Page 3
```

Comment: updated layout file.I tried giving a tab..but that didn'nt help

Comment: Thanks for the help..Is there a way to format my code quickly? i'm facing a lot of trouble with this

Comment: @MohammedAjmal Actually pugjs will work with normal html code inside pug template. I would advise you to read up on the documentation and lastly i used https://html2jade.org/ to help me render html to pug format